# Site not working after removal of Index.php from urlstring?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

In my old url it was http://localhost/midas/index.php

My site is using MVC framwork with CodeIgniter.

I activated mod_rewrite in Apache XAMPP and used the following htaccess code:

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

When I enter my base url it is fine and my home page loads up:

base url = http://localhost/midas/

However when I click on my navigation menu or links I get a 404 object not found error message.

Apache Error Message:

[Tue Jul 12 13:48:55 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/midas/site, referer: http://localhost/midas/

Is there something I need to change somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/application/config/config.php` and change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also, you will need to restart Apache after you've enabled `mod_rewrite`.

This is the `.htaccess` I'm using with CodeIgniter (modified so it should work for you):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /midas/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

It should be in your root directory (i.e. `C:\xampp\htdocs\midas`).

Comment: See http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/ (where I got `.htaccess` from) for further reference.

Comment: If you still have issues, you may also need to change `$config['uri_protocol']` from default `AUTO` value to `QUERY_STRING` or `REQUEST_URI`.

Comment: Hi I used your htaccess and placed it into midas directory. EDIT - Ok when I click a button on my webpage it now takes me to the xampp server page?

Comment: Ok i dont know what I did but its working now however when I click my home button it takes me to the xampp server page.

Comment: Okay my when I click on my About page it takes me to the XAMPP page too

Comment: What do your links look like at the moment? Are they relative (e.g. `<a href="/go/there">There</a>`)?

Comment: This echo '<li>', anchor('site/about', 'About'), '</li>';

I check with firebug and it says it finds the page "302" but then It takes me to XAMPP home page.

Comment: It says in firebug GET about.php 301 moved permanently , GET about.php 302 found

Comment: @stealthyninja let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1373/discussion-between-bob-and-stealthyninja)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set a RewriteBase in your htaccess

see: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

My guess would be

```
RewriteBase /midas
```

(right after `RewriteEngine`)